# Missing "key" prop for element in iterator, While uploaded in vercel and netlify

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, netlify, vercel

```
import Link from "next/link";
import { withRouter } from "next/router";

function Navbar({  router }) {
const  navs = [

    { text: 'Home', href:'/'},
    { text: 'About', href:'/about'},
    { text: 'Portfolio', href:'/portfolio'},
    { text: 'Contact', href:'/contact'},
  ];
  return (
        <ul className="nav-links">
          {navs.map(nav => ( 
          <li><Link href={nav.href} className={`nav-item ${ router.pathname == nav.href ?  'active' : ''}`}>{nav.text}</Link></li> 
          ))}
        </ul>
      </div>
     </nav>
  );`
}

export default withRouter(Navbar);
```

> I am new in next.js, i cannot upload my web to vercel and netlify because i get an error while upload it, can anyone help me please ?

Answer (score 0):

To fix your error, I suggest you to add the "key" key to the first component of your map.
See code below :

```js
import Link from "next/link";
import { withRouter } from "next/router";

function Navbar({  router }) {
const  navs = [

    { text: 'Home', href:'/'},
    { text: 'About', href:'/about'},
    { text: 'Portfolio', href:'/portfolio'},
    { text: 'Contact', href:'/contact'},
  ];
  return (
        <ul className="nav-links">
          {navs.map((nav, index) => ( 
          <li key={index}><Link href={nav.href} className={`nav-item ${ router.pathname == nav.href ?  'active' : ''}`}>{nav.text}</Link></li> 
          ))}
        </ul>
      </div>
     </nav>
  );`
}

export default withRouter(Navbar);
```

A more focused view. I add the "key" key to the first elem of the map:

```js
{navs.map((nav, index) => ( 
    <li key={index}><Link href={nav.href} className={`nav-item ${ router.pathname == nav.href ?  'active' : ''}`}>{nav.text}</Link></li> 
))}
```

Comment: Ideally we [shouldn't be using index as keys](https://dev.to/shiv1998/why-not-to-use-index-as-key-in-react-lists-practical-example-3e66).

Comment: I know that, in my opinion for beginners, it is easier to understand that it is another type of key.

Comment: Thanks a lot my friend, the error is fixed and i can deploy my project now

Comment: No problem, if it's working, can you upvote and validate the answer ? Thanks ^^